# which is the approach on relative detail and constant detail in dyntopo sculpting?

Tags: dynamic-topology

Hi I am wondering about dyntopo, at the begginig of the sculpting, suppose I am starting to put details on a base mesh to start sculpting, should I star with constant detail? to get the curve and sharp forms of my model? then I shoul use relative detail ? with 5 to 20 of details?